# Multinomial logistic regression for stacked ensemble learning with 2d input into regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, ensemble-learning

I am trying to implement a stacked ensemble model for multiclass prediction.

Each training example is a vector with 14 features.
There are a total of 12 possible classes.
The three base models (described below) each ingest a 14-dimensional feature vector training example and output a 12-dimensional vector of probabilities (1 probability / class).

The three base classification models were built from scratch (i.e. not built using `sklearn` so I can't simply use the `sklearn` ensemble methods) and are as follows:

- Bayes Net: outputs a 12-dimensional vector of probabilities (1 probability / class) for each 14-dimensional training example
- Other graphical model: outputs a 12-dimensional vector of probabilities (1 probability / class) for each 14-dimensional training example
- Metric learning model: outputs a 12-dimensional vector of probabilities (1 probability / class) for each 14-dimensional training example

I would like to stack the outputs from the base models for each training example (i.e. stack 3 x 12-d probability vectors) for each training example and feed this 3x12 array as an input to the multinomial logistic regression ensemble model to output a 12-dimensional vector of probabilities for the final multi-class predictions for each training example.

I'm not sure, however, if this is possible using the `sklearn` multinomial regression model.  From my understanding, the `sklearn` model can only ingest a 1-d array of features rather than a 2-d array of features.

Any advice would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So the ultimate workaround ended up being very simple: flattening the `3x12` vector outputs for each base model into a `1x36` feature vector that was then fed into the ensemble model.

The other option was to build a tensor out of the base model predictions and then use a different type of ensemble classifier i.e. a CNN, but that approach was rejected.